# What could cause those speckles on my printer's output?

Tags: printing, printer, laser-printer, color-printer

A while ago, I have bought a used HP CP5225dn printer. I knew that the device was not 100% OK, but the price was very good, and a complete set of nearly new toner cartridges was included, so I decided to buy despite the following drawback:

When I print something, there are often speckles in the output like the ones shown in the image below. This happens independently of the sort of paper (glossy, normal), of the size (e.g. A4 or A3, but see below) and of whether I print in color or black / white.

I always adjust the printing options according to the sort of paper I actually use, and I always use the highest possible print quality in the driver; therefore, I am confident that the problem is not due to my own mistake.

The speckles do not appear on every page, though. I'd say that they appear at various positions approximately on two thirds or at least on the half of A4 pages I print. I didn't print a large number of A3 pages so far, so I can't tell for sure, but it seems that the speckles are nearly on all A3 pages.

Since I am not that deep in color laser printing technology, I'd like to ask for possible reasons for that problem. I am hoping that somebody who is experienced with color laser printers can help me out.

For the moment being, I don't want to bring that printer to a repair center, because there is no such center near me, and the shipping costs would be substantial if I send it via DHL or another carrier. Instead, I'd like to learn about possible reasons for the problem and try to replace defective parts myself.

[image: Speckles in the CP5225dn's output]

Comment: Looks like dirt on the rollers, have you tried replacing them or cleaning them with alcohol?

Comment: Thank you very much, and +1. I'll try this and report back. Maybe I'll need a few days to do it, though.

Comment: Please check the model number you gave. According to https://www.hp.com/au-en/shop/hp-color-laserjet-pro-cp5225dn-printer-ce712a.html this is an A4 printer, not A3.

Comment: @hdhondt HP's website is often misleading, and the page you have linked has been made by total idiots (look how they spell Ethernet right at the beginning). The CP5225dn is definitely A3. At the page you have linked, there is a button "See more specs"; if you hit it, a list of specifications opens. If you scroll down that list (quite far), you'll notice some entries "Media Size". There you can see the media sizes supported by the various trays, A3 being among them. So HP managed to make the most important information and the USP for that product invisible in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Further to my comment, apologies, I should have looked below the first screen!

Assuming the marks always appear on A3, are they always in the same place? I assume they do not repeat down the page. If they don't, then the culprit has to be a component that is the size of an A3 page. If the culprit were a roller, the marks would repeat at a distance equal to the circumference of the guilty roller. "Rollers" includes the drums and the fuser.

To my mind that leaves only one possibility: the transfer belt. This is an expensive consumable, which collects the entire 4-colour image before it is transferred to the paper. It's available as part of a "maintenance kit" which also includes a full set of rollers.

I would start by taking it out and inspecting it for any marks. If there are any, you can try to remove them with isopropyl alcohol (or methylated spirits, if necessary). Make sure you do not touch the actual belt with your fingers.

This [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gDQBXNZaEr0) shows how to clean it. It also stresses not rotating it the wrong way.

If that does not help, then replacement is the only way. However, it does carry a [$529 price tag](https://www.precisionroller.com/maintenance-kits-for-hp-color-laserjet-pro-cp5225dn/details_66559.html); if that does not put you off, replacing all the other rollers in the kit is a good idea for an old printer.

I had a quick look for manuals that could explain how to remove the transfer belt. Unfortunately, in typical HP fashion, I could not find any manual that might help. So, just open all doors and panels. The transfer belt should be easily identifiable, and there should be coloured latches holding it in.

**EDIT**
I finally found a user manual, on a [manuals website](https://www.manua.ls/hp/color-laserjet-professional-cp5225dn/manual), not HP's. As expected, it does not even mention the transfer belt. However, [this page](https://www.metrofuser.com/post/how-to-replace-the-cp5525-cp5225-m750-and-m775-transfer-belt-w-page-count-resets-instructions) shows how to remove it, as well as how to reset its page counter.

Answer (score 0):

If the pattern of dots is the same and occurs at the same distance (across sheets) every time, you likely have a dirty or damaged transfer belt.

Repeating defects from other parts, like the drum or fuser, will appear several times on each page. But only the transfer belt is large enough to cause image defects to appear, say, every other page.